# perl - create file name from column names

Tags: regex, perl, filenames

I am new to Perl and I would like to create the name of the output file based on the column names present in the input file. Say that my input file header is the following:

```
#identifier    (%)composition
```

and I would like my output file name to be `identifier_composition`. These `identifiers` and `compositions` can be a sequence of alphanumeric characters such as `#E2FAR4` for identifier or `(%)MhDE4` for composition. For this example, the output file name should be `E2FAR4_MhDE4`. So far, I am able to get the `identifier` but not the `composition`. This is what I have tried as code:

```
if ($line =~ /^#\s*(\S+)\t\(%)s*(\S+)/){
    my $ID = $1;
    my $comp = $2;
    my $out_file = "${ID}_${comp}"
}
```

but I get the `identifier` also as the second argument. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `$line =~ /^#\W*(\w+)\t\W*(\w+)/`

Comment: parenthesis are special characters in regex, escape them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below regex

```
^#\s*(\S+)\t\(%\)(\S+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cOcY39/1)

Example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
while(<DATA>){
    my $line = $_;
    chomp $line;
    if ($line =~ /^#\s*(\S+)\t\(%\)(\S+)/){
        my $ID = $1;
        my $comp = $2;
        my $out_file = "${ID}_${comp}";
        print "Filename: $out_file";
    }
}

__DATA__
#identifier (%)composition
```

Output:

```
Filename: identifier_composition
```

Comment: Thank you. It works and can be easily adapted for any value the `identifier` and `composition` may take as well as the (eventual) preceding special characters.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're rather over-thinking your regex. You're looking for two sequences of word characters separated by some non-word characters.

```
if ($line =~ /(\w+)\W+(\w+)/) {
  say "$1 / $2";
}
```

An even simpler approach would be to match all sequences of word characters:

```
if (my @words = $line =~ /(\w+)/g) {
  say join ' / ', @words;
}
```

**Update:** I put your regex into this [regex explainer](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl). Here's what came out:

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  #                        '#'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S+                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ") (1 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \t                       '\t' (tab)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \^                       '^'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %                        '%'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  s*                       's' (0 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S+                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ") (1 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
```

I think your biggest problem was the literal `^` that you were trying to match in the middle of the regex, but the unescaped parentheses around the `%` were a problem too. And the `s*` is pointless and confusing :-)

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the elaborate response. Yes, that `^` was actually a copy/paste error in my question. Was not actually part of my code, but I leave it there because your answer is referring to it. It is true that it works for the example I gave, but the identifier and the composition are not necessarily literally `identifier` and `composition` it can be very well a sequence of alphanumeric characters preceded by some special character and separated by a tab. But thank you once again for your time.

Comment: @Marius: If you want a meaningful answer, then your question should include sample data that demonstrates the range of possibilities :-)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have edited the question text accordingly. Thanks once again